# commands not executing with laravel cron jobs

Tags: laravel

i am hosting my laravel application with namecheap, i have also followed all the instructions here https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9453/29/how-to-run-scripts-via-cron-jobs . however after setting my cron job in the cron job tab of cpanel, i get notifications in my email but the artisan command does'nt seem to be executed as my database remains the same. i tried to echo out a value in the artisan command's handle method for testing purposes but then nothing gets output and i still get notifications in my email like so => 'Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' deactivate:ads > '/home/agrodqkc/applications/agroexpresslink/app/console/log.txt' 2>&1 &'

This is my cron command for every minute => /usr/local/bin/php /home/agrodqkc/applications/agroexpresslink/artisan schedule:run

my kernel.php file :

```
<?php

namespace mazee\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    // Commands\Inspire::class,
      Commands\maz::class,
      Commands\deactivateads::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();

    //$schedule->command('maz:do')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(base_path().'/app/console/log.txt')->emailOutputTo('ewomaukah@yahoo.com');;
    $schedule->command('deactivate:ads')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo( base_path().'/app/console/log.txt');
}
```

}

Comment: Well, sometimes shared host providers put some limits on cron execution time. It might be restricting you from running scripts every minute. Please confirm with Namecheap for that.

Comment: Ok. I found this. 
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1212/22/do-you-allow-cron-jobs

Comment: @RajenderJoshi i tried to run => php artisan schedule:run through ssh and it worked properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you show the cron command that you are running because I think the cron job is not set properly

if you access your server using ssh and enter crontab -e 
OR
You might have a dedicated tool to set cronjobs in cPanel

The CRON job should be set as following:

```
* * * * * /opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php /home/agrodqkc/applications/agroexpresslink/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The above command will run every minute and will search for scheduled tasks.

Comment: this is the command i'm running => * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/agrodqkc/applications/agroexpresslink/artisan schedule:run

Comment: i'm getting an email every minute that the scheduled command was run but however its not executing anything in the 'handle' method of the the artisan command.  the content of the email is this => "Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' deactivate:ads > '/home/agrodqkc/applications/agroexpresslink/app/console/log.txt' 2>&1 &"

Comment: I belive /opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' deactivate:ads this command throws error as there is no artisan file in /opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php directory and the error lies in your cron job command

Comment: i tried to run => 'php artisan schedule:run'    through ssh and it worked properly

Comment: my current working directory is '/home/agrodqkc/applications/agroexpresslink/ '. my laravel appllication resides there.

Comment: its working now !! i think namecheap had a way of preventing it from running every minute...i tried running it every 15 minutes and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got mine to work after days of frustration i discovered that because laravel app requires you to put public files of your app in public_html folder and main files on your separate folder outside of public_html so to register a cron job use this

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/separatefolder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```